# Migrate Confluence to Github wiki (Gollum)

Tags: github, migration, wiki, confluence, gollum-wiki

Does somebody know a nice way to migrate a **Confluence** wiki to the **Github** wiki (aka Gollum) ?

By *nice way* I mean quick and effective.

Answer (score 8):

You can export whole spaces to html format, and than use [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) to rewrite pages to ReST|Markdown

Comment: Export to html and this page worked for me: https://domchristie.github.io/to-markdown/

Comment: There is no option to `export to html`. Only options are these: http://imgur.com/YOFFgjA

Comment: Export to html, requires "export space" privilege. It's available from space administration, as in doc: https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/exporting-confluence-pages-and-spaces-to-html-658736966.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I threw together some Python code to do this:

https://github.com/gergelykalman/confluence-markdown-exporter

It is pretty basic but it worked well for me.